# Use Node js to to print data to thermal printer

Tags: node.js, printing

I'm developing an application with Node JS where I need to see all available printers in the user's machine, let the user select one of them and print a receipt.

Is there a way to achieve this in macOS and Windows ?

Note , I have checked all examples in internet,nothing helped. Kindly provide me an complete example.

Comment: It depends entirely on the printer, and whether or not it has osx drivers. If it doesn't, and it uses a serial protocol (e.g., over USB) then you can write to it directly via node-serial. If it has drivers them normal printing stuff applies.

Comment: Have a look at this library: https://github.com/Klemen1337/node-thermal-printer

Answer (score 1):

In googling there are few libraries that does this job...

Take a look on [printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/printer) for example, it does all the jobs you require...

`getPrinters()` to enumerate all installed printers with current jobs and statuses;

```
getPrinter(printerName)
```

There a many examples in the github repo to help you :

https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer/tree/master/examples

Comment: App threw an error during load
Error: The module '/Users/siva-8334/Documents/Projects/node-printer-master/lib/node_printer.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 75. Please try re-compiling or re-installing.

Tried both npm rebuild and npm install. Didn't work please help

Comment: @SivaKumar Have you read the doc ? How to install and do what is needed ? https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer#how-to-install